# Accessing a private method within a class is giving a name error saying it is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, class, nameerror

I'm creating a class with this method that computes for the centroid of a given area from coordinates. This is [my code](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/payiluqutu.rb) so far. And I'm having this error in jupyter notebook : *NameError: name '_Lot__getCentroid' is not defined*. What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to just follow this UML given to me. Should I move the method getCentroid first before the initialization? I'm not sure that's customary with classes but I'm new to it so I don't know. [image: UML]

Comment: you dont need to use staticmethod for private functions, use self in function declaration and function calling

Comment: @sahasrara62 i thought "@staticmethod" allows me to make a function that has no self as an argument? I was trying to follow the uml. Or am i misinterpreting the UML as well?

Comment: Can a static method can be called on an instantiated object ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There two reasons why your code will not work:

1. `self.centroid = __getCentroid()` will work only if `__getCentroid()` function will be declared outside the class. If it's inside the class, you should call `self.__getCentroid()`
2. `__getCentroid()` is a static method and has no access to class or instance attributes. So you don't have access to `self.*something*`. If you use IDE such a Pycharm, it will show you the error.

Just read a little bit more about classes, their attributes and methods in python :)

Comment: If I remove the staticmethod, can I make the getCentroid function without the argument "self" ? Or is it necessary since i want to access the vertices in the initialization?

Comment: And btw thank you! Do you have any recommendations on what I can read for classes? The ones I've seen so far have basic examples that don't show about private functions.

Comment: Yes, you need to have `self` argument to access attributes. And looking at your code I don't see any problems in that, because you are already working with class object. 
About what to read - try this (about different methods) https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/